# Can't get to console using Ctrl + Alt + 1; low graphics mode

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, shortcut-keys, console

I have incorrectly installed video drivers on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to enter console during boot up using Ctrl + Alt + F1 I am able to enter it for few seconds. After that I get message system is running in low graphics mode.

I am unable to dismiss it. If I press Ctrl + Alt + F1 I get blank black screen without prompt. I must restart system using buttons.

How can I get to console in this case to remove incorrectly installed driver?

Comment: Does it work with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` ? And return to graphic mode with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F7`

Comment: If that does not work, you can  try to reboot with the boot option `nomodeset`

Comment: @sudodus nomodeset does nothing in my case. Any other idea?

Comment: Please specify your computer:
 Brand name and model
- CPU
- RAM (size)
- graphics chip/card
- wifi chip/card. - And which video driver did you install and how did you install it?

Comment: Dell Inspirion 3721, Intel i7, 4GB. Radeon (don't know exact model), Broadcom WiFi, but using wired. I installed fglrx using "sudo apt-get install fglrx".

Comment: The proprietary driver for Radeon graphics should work in 14.04 LTS, at least for many cards/chips, but maybe not for your model. I am using nvidia, so I know very little about Radeon. With some luck someone who knows will find your question, so *please edit the question* and add all possible information about your graphics card/chip. - Otherwise, how much is installed in your current system? Maybe it is easiest to save your personal files and make a fresh installation of 16.04.1 LTS, which has an improved free driver for radeon graphics (but no proprietary version). Try 16.04.1 LTS *live* :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I was hoping Ubuntu 14.04. is "smarter" and that would not have to install from scratch like I had with 12.04. but obviously it is not the case. Seriously considering going back to Windows after 7 years giving chance to Linux :(